# Spring Security - Apply pattern to custom http filter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I use Spring Security 3.0 and I would like to define a Basic Authentication filter only on a specific subset of URLs in my application.

Is it possible to add a pattern to custom-filters ?

I would like to add a **pattern** attribute like this :

```
<security:custom-filter ref="basicAuthenticationFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" pattern="/services/**"/>
```

I saw it is possible to use **filters** attribute on **intercept-url** but I would not have to list them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a `filer-chain-map` to solve this issue.

```
    <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/ws/**" filters="basicAuthenticationFilter"/>
    </security:filter-chain-map>
```

There might be a better solution though.

Comment: It works as expected but doing this seems to create a valid session that can be used for non-matching URL afterwards. This is a logical behavior but I would like that session to be valid only for the pattern-matching URLs. Should I inspect and invalidate the session ? based on what ?